# How to get matrix values of 3D image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d

I am doing a new project in *MATLAB*. I need to convert a 2D image to a 3D image and get the matrix values of 3D image for processing (i.e) for face-recognition.

I already tried `imshow3D`.

```
imshow3D(Image)
```

I expect the code to convert a 2D image to a 3D image and get pixel values of 3D image.

Comment: I am not sure, `imshow3D`, does what you are expecting. As per this link [imshow3D](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41334-imshow3d), this function, _"displays 3D grayscale or RGB images in a slice by slice fashion with mouse-based slice browsing and window and level adjustment control, and auto slice browsing control."_

Comment: p.s. To construct a 3D-image, from a 'single' 2D-image is not possible. There is missing information - about the 3rd dimension. What is possible however is constructing a 3D-image using multiple 2D-images.